# Is there a term-of-art for 'to take in art'?

Tags: single-word-requests

Philosophers agree that emotional elicitivity is an essential element of art. Often, whether a work elicits emotion in a given person continges on the satisfaction of two conditions:

1. the person observes the work, and
2. while he observes the work, he, in some sense, allows the work to elicit whatever emotions it will elicit in him.

As such, the verb *observe* doesn't entail the satisfaction of the second condition.

I considered the verb *appreciate*; however, the satisfaction of the two conditions doesn't necessitate that the observer appreciates the work.

Hence my question: is there a term of art that means 'to take in a work of art'?

I'd favour answers that mention a term that isn't a metaphor and that doesn't entail the sense that the observer uses to observe the work.

Thank you,

-Hal

Comment: *Absorb*, *consume*, *contemplate*, *indulge*.

Answer (score 1):

Condition one, that *the person observes the work*, really shouldn't be included as a condition (it is rather a predicate or *pre*condition); obviously one can have no response to a work of art that one has not observed or experienced. So, the crux of the question then becomes, what term is appropriate for one who allows or permits a work of art to have an affect, or make an impression, upon them?

The first requirement would be that one is *receptive* or *open* to such a subjective response. One is either *receptive* or *open* to a work of art, or one is not. If not *receptive* or *open*, nothing more can be expected; if, on the other hand, one is *receptive* or *open* then the possibility of a complex subjective experience of the work of art is possible.

To "*take in*" is to receive, thus it is common to hear the expression, one is "receptive" or emotionally *receptive* to a work, or works, of art

> **RECEPTIVE** *adjective*:
>
> **1**: able or inclined to receive; especially :  open and responsive to ideas, impressions, or suggestions; • receptively *adverb*; • receptiveness *noun*
>   see, Merriam-Webster Dictionary [**receptive**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/receptive)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Disagree re: comment on the first condition. A precondition is a kind of condition. As such, it is a condition.

Answer (score 1):

[Internalize/Interiorize](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/interiorize) suggest  a profound contact with something to the point of feeling it as  part of yourself:

> - To cause (feelings, for example) to become an interior or internal part of one's mental or spiritual being; "In ... earlier movies, [he] interiorized emotion so much that he became inexpressive" (Pauline Kael). (TFD)

Answer (score 1):

*Appreciate* is the word you will generally see associated with the contemplation and enjoyment of art. It certainly means more than more than taking in art just because it's there, but it is doesn't have the depth that you are asking about, which may be what is described in "A Zen Lesson in Art Appreciation":

> **A Zen approach to art (appreciation)** means experiencing art, or receiving art, with total mindfulness. Let your preconceptions go. Let your assumptions go. Let go of your urge to compare what you experience with anything else. (From *[The Complete Idiot's Guide to Zen Living](https://books.google.com/books?id=YqRaeMiWknMC&pg=PA300&lpg=PA300&dq=zen%20of%20art%20appreciation&source=bl&ots=VB3OaHrf8W&sig=bWJGCdZPr6JGLXL29L8g-33PW_U&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GQkLVcb_NIe_ggSo3IGoAg&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=zen%20of%20art%20appreciation&f=false), by Gary McClain and Eve Adamson*)

If there is a single word for this, I would have expected the authors to have suggested it. But as far as I can tell, they didn't provide one.